# Convert a string formula into its result php

Tags: php, parsing, formula

I have a string formula which I fetch from a file :

```
  $text = "100*20";
```

I want to find a way to convert this formula into its result, for instance have the value 200.
Is this possible using php?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Use [eval()](http://de.php.net/manual/en/function.eval.php).

```
$expression = '100*20';
eval('$result = ('.$expression.')');
echo $result;
```

Comment: No no no.  Don't direct people to use `eval` for math operations especially when there are so many solutions out there that are actually safe to use.

Answer (score -1):

Make sure to investigate the security issues surrounding `eval();`.

As the data is from a file it may be ok, but if it is user input - don't.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. If you [earn](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/146472/169503) sufficient [reputation](//stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](//stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).